# jquery hover propagation

Tags: jquery, hover, fadeto

I'm using this on an hover image :

```
$('.img-style').hover (function(e) {
    var prixPlus = $(this).closest('a').attr('data-prix'); 
    prixPlus = parseFloat(prixPlus);
    var prixNew = prix + prixPlus;

    $('#chgePrix').html(prixNew.toFixed(2));
    $('#txtapart').fadeTo('fast', 0.1);
}, function(e) {
    $('#chgePrix').html(prix.toFixed(2));
    $('#txtapart').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
```

But if I pass quickly the mouse 2 or more times over the image, $('#txtapart') fade in and out 2 or more times ! How can I stop the fade propagation ?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: So it does what you want, but too quickly?

Comment: This snippet works fine but if I pass 10 times the mouse over the image quickly... I need the FADE stop if I'am not on the image anymore (sorry for my english !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `stop()` method

```
 $('#txtapart').stop(true,true).fadeTo('fast', 0.1);
```

This forces prior animation to end. The two `true` arguments clear the queue and set animation at it's end point so that the new animation can start immediately when other event is trigegred.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

The function is getting called on every mouseover.  There's no good way to detect if a function is already running in Javascript.

Comment: not true in jquery animations, several ways to detect if animation in progress including `is(':animated')`